# Selenium, Java: выбрать элемент выпадающего списка, если на странице он представлен одновременно select и ul li, и Selenium не видит их оба

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

Использую Selenium, java. Задача: получить список элементов для двух выпадающих списков и кликнуть на один из полученных элементов в обоих списках.
Однако если с первым списком **select name="ppw-expirationDate_month"** никаких проблем не возникло, выбрала нужную опцию с помощью класса Select, то со вторым возникла странная проблема: сначала показалось, что он точно так же, как и первый, представлен селектом: **select name="ppw-expirationDate_year"**, однако при попытке обработать его так же, как и первый, я получила ошибку *"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:"* 
При этом при наведении на option-ы для этого списка в Инструментах разработчика они не выделялись в открытом списке.

```html
<div class="a-section a-spacing-none pmts-expiry pmts-date-width">
      <label for="pp-YP-43" id="pp-YP-44" class="a-form-label">Expiration date</label>
      <span class="a-dropdown-container">
      <select name="ppw-expirationDate_month" autocomplete="off" data-a-native-class="pmts-native-dropdown" id="pp-YP-43" tabindex="-1" class="a-native-dropdown pmts-native-dropdown">
        <option value="1" selected="">01</option>
        <option value="2">02</option>
        <option value="3">03</option>
        <option value="4">04</option>
        <option value="5">05</option>
        <option value="6">06</option>
        <option value="7">07</option>
        <option value="8">08</option>
        <option value="9">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
      </select>
      <span tabindex="-1" id="pp-YP-46" data-pmts-component-id="pp-YP-29" data-a-class="pmts-expiry-month pmts-portal-component pmts-portal-components-pp-YP-29" class="a-button a-button-dropdown pmts-expiry-month pmts-portal-component pmts-portal-components-pp-YP-29" style="min-width: 0.166667%;">
      <span class="a-button-inner">
      <span class="a-button-text a-declarative" data-action="a-dropdown-button" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true">
      <span class="a-dropdown-prompt">03</span>
      </span>
      <i
        class="a-icon a-icon-dropdown"></i>
      </span>
      </span>
      </span>
      <span class="a-letter-space"></span>
      <span class="a-dropdown-container">
        <select name="ppw-expirationDate_year" autocomplete="off" data-a-native-class="pmts-native-dropdown" id="pp-YP-45" tabindex="-1" class="a-native-dropdown pmts-native-dropdown">
          <option value="2018" selected="">2018</option>
          <option value="2019">2019</option>
          <option value="2020">2020</option>
          <option value="2021">2021</option>
          <option value="2022">2022</option>
          <option value="2023">2023</option>
          <option value="2024">2024</option>
          <option value="2025">2025</option>
          <option value="2026">2026</option>
        </select>
        <span tabindex="-1" id="pp-YP-47" data-pmts-component-id="pp-YP-29" data-a-class="pmts-expiry-year pmts-portal-component pmts-portal-components-pp-YP-29" class="a-button a-button-dropdown pmts-expiry-year pmts-portal-component pmts-portal-components-pp-YP-29" style="min-width: 0%;">
        <span class="a-button-inner">
        <span class="a-button-text a-declarative" data-action="a-dropdown-button" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="a-dropdown-prompt">2018</span>
        </span>
        <i
          class="a-icon a-icon-dropdown"></i>
          </span>
          </span>
          </span>
    </div>
```

При дальнейшем рассмотрении страницы обнаружила, что на ней есть дублирующий список для этой кнопки, и его можно найти, если открыть список и проинспектировать элементы внутри, но представлен он на странице ниже список ul li:

```html
<div class="a-popover a-dropdown a-dropdown-common a-declarative" data-action="a-popover-a11y" id="a-popover-3" aria-hidden="false" style="z-index: 299; visibility: visible; top: 129px; left: 401.25px;"><span tabindex="0" role="dialog" class="a-popover-start a-popover-a11y-offscreen"></span>
  <div class="a-popover-wrapper">
    <div class="a-popover-inner" style="height: auto; overflow-y: auto; min-width: 71px; width: auto;">
      <ul tabindex="-1" class="a-nostyle a-list-link" role="listbox" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <li tabindex="0" role="option" aria-checked="true" aria-labelledby="pp-YP-45_0" class="a-dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="{&quot;stringVal&quot;:&quot;2018&quot;}" id="pp-YP-45_0" class="a-dropdown-link a-active">2018</a></li>
        <li tabindex="0" role="option" aria-labelledby="pp-YP-45_1" class="a-dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="{&quot;stringVal&quot;:&quot;2019&quot;}" id="pp-YP-45_1" class="a-dropdown-link">2019</a></li>
        <li tabindex="0" role="option" aria-labelledby="pp-YP-45_2" class="a-dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="{&quot;stringVal&quot;:&quot;2020&quot;}" id="pp-YP-45_2" class="a-dropdown-link">2020</a></li>
        <li tabindex="0" role="option" aria-labelledby="pp-YP-45_3" class="a-dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="{&quot;stringVal&quot;:&quot;2021&quot;}" id="pp-YP-45_3" class="a-dropdown-link">2021</a></li>
        <li tabindex="0" role="option" aria-labelledby="pp-YP-45_4" class="a-dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="{&quot;stringVal&quot;:&quot;2022&quot;}" id="pp-YP-45_4" class="a-dropdown-link">2022</a></li>
        <li tabindex="0" role="option" aria-labelledby="pp-YP-45_5" class="a-dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="{&quot;stringVal&quot;:&quot;2023&quot;}" id="pp-YP-45_5" class="a-dropdown-link">2023</a></li>
        <li tabindex="0" role="option" aria-labelledby="pp-YP-45_6" class="a-dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="{&quot;stringVal&quot;:&quot;2024&quot;}" id="pp-YP-45_6" class="a-dropdown-link">2024</a></li>
        <li tabindex="0" role="option" aria-labelledby="pp-YP-45_7" class="a-dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="{&quot;stringVal&quot;:&quot;2025&quot;}" id="pp-YP-45_7" class="a-dropdown-link">2025</a></li>
        <li tabindex="0" role="option" aria-labelledby="pp-YP-45_8" class="a-dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="{&quot;stringVal&quot;:&quot;2026&quot;}" id="pp-YP-45_8" class="a-dropdown-link">2026</a></li>
    </div>
  </div><span tabindex="0" class="a-popover-end a-popover-a11y-offscreen"></span></div>
```

И вот если наводиться на элементы в нем в Инструментах разработчика, то они выделяются на странице. Попыталась получить список элементов следующим образом:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name="ppw-expirationDate_year"]/following-sibling::span")).click();
    WebElement ulElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("\"//ul[@role=\"listbox\"]"));
    List<WebElement> listbox = ulElement.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```

Но получаю ошибку *Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression "//ul[@role="listbox"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '"//ul[@role="listbox"]' is not a valid XPath expression.*

С первым списком, с которым не было проблем, справилась так:

```
WebElement selectMonth = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name=\"ppw-expirationDate_month\"]"));
    Select select = new Select(selectMonth);
    select.selectByVisibleText("03");
```

Что я делаю не так со вторым списком и почему на странице вообще он представлен одновременно селектом и ul li?

Comment: Получить список элементов получилось так: WebDriverWait ulWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        ulWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@role=\"listbox\"]")));
        WebElement ulElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@role=\"listbox\"]"));
        List<WebElement> listbox = ulElement.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        for (WebElement box : listbox){
            if(box.getText()=="2020"){
                box.click();
                break;}}   Тест проходит без ошибок, однако опции не выбираются. New problem to solve

Answer (score 0):

Решение всего:

```
WebDriverWait ulWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    ulWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@role=\"listbox\"]")));
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("2020")).click();
```